# How to check that a string contains at least 5 unique characters and is minimum 7 characters long?

Tags: php, regex

I need a validation that tests for a string that contains 5 unique characters and is at least 7 characters long.

I have already tried it with the following regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{7}$
```

I'm stuck and have no idea how to do the validation so that the string contains at least 5 unique characters.

Comment: This doesn't address your underlying need, but just a note of clarification, as written, your regular expression (/^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{7}$/) will match strings meeting the following criteria (1) starts with an English letter (ignoring case), (2) ends with 7 digits (0-9).  I think you mean /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}$/, which should match any string that contains _exactly_ 7 English-letter or numeric digit characters.  That's still not what you're really looking for, but it may help clarify a bit.

Comment: I want it in PHP but if we cannot get it in PHP we can try using javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think this would be easy to check if you have at least 5 unique characters in there with a regex, so I use another approach.

I check with [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), that your string only contains characters from this [character class](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) `[a-zA-Z0-9]` and is at least 7 characters long, which I check with a [quantifier](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php): `{7,}`.

Then to make sure you have >= 5 unique characters, I split your string into an array with [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php), get all unique characters with [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) and check with [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) if there are >= 5 unique characters, e.g.

```
if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{7,}$/", $input) && count(array_unique(str_split($input))) >= 5) {
    //good
} else {
    /bad
}
```

---

As, from question it is not clear if you want to perform validation in [php](/questions/tagged/php) or [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), adding the similar code using Javascript.

```js
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{7,}$/;

// Adding method on prototype, so that can be invoked on array
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
  var arr = this; // Cache array

  // Return the array by removing duplicates
  return this.filter(function(e, i) {
    return arr.indexOf(e) === i;
  });
};

// Binding keyup event on textbox(Demo Purpose)
document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  var str = this.value; // Get value

  this.classList.remove('invalid'); // Remove classes

  // Check if regex satisfies, and there are unique elements than required
  if (regex.test(str) && str.split('').unique().length >= 5) {
    console.log('Valid');
    this.classList.add('valid'); // Demo Purpose
  } else {
    console.log('Invalid');
    this.classList.add('invalid'); // Demo Purpose
  }
}, false);
```

```css
.valid {
  border: solid 1px green;
}
.invalid {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<input id="text" type="text" />
```

---

Just for the completeness, here would be a solution only with a regex:

```
~^
  (?=.{7,})
    ([a-z\d])[a-z\d]*
    (?!\1)([a-z\d])[a-z\d]*
    (?!\1|\2)([a-z\d])[a-z\d]*
    (?!\1|\2|\3)([a-z\d])[a-z\d]*
    (?!\1|\2|\3|\4)([a-z\d])[a-z\d]*
$~i
```

Simply explained:

- `(?=.{7,})` makes sure that from the start till the end of the string there are at least 7 characters
- Then there are 5 capturing groups with negative lookahead's, which make sure their match can't be in any other of the 4 capturing groups. So this makes sure there are at least 5 unique characters in the string
- The `[a-z\d]*` around the capturing groups and negative lookahead's are simply there to say, that there can be all kinds of stuff around these 5 unique characters

(The regex could maybe still be optimized)

Comment: Thanks PHP  is fine by me

Comment: @Geek updated the answer with a pure regex answer, just for completeness and to show you that it's possible.

Comment: Thanks mate you are a life saver :)

Answer (score 0):

You want {6,} for seven or more, I think.  You'll probably need to do something besides a regex for "5 or more different"

Or maybe ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{7,} if you had the brackets wrong.

I don't know php, but here's the algorithm I would use for the 5 diff part:

```
int seen[256] = {0};
int ndiff = 0;
for each char c in string {
    seen[c]++;
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
     if (seen[i]) ndiff++;
  }
```

Comment: I want to do it as 5 or more 
sorry for my ignorance 
It don't need to be exactly regex we can try in some other ways even,Just need the job to be done,Thanks

Comment: By 5 different, I assume you mean 'aaaabcd' does not pass, but 'aaabcde' does.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you have too many brackets
 @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}$ "

Comment: It expect exact 7 chars if you use {7}, you should use {7,} instead